# Where to put SSL encryption, Apache HTTP or Webapp

Tags: apache, web-services, ssl, erlang, cowboy

I'm creating an Middleware/Webapp for a REST API in Erlang with cowboy framework and Apache HTTP with ModProxy, to redirect requests from port 80 to port 80xx, since i don't wanna use custom ports to listen requests and i don't wanna run the code in root to be able to listen in port 80.

Now i wanna encrypt the connections, with SSL, using HTTPS and my question is: where is the best practice to configure SSL with certificates, keys etc, in Apache HTTP (before redirect with ModProxy) or in Cowboy framework in Erlang app, since both support SSL configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off topic: If you want to sound professional, don't say "I wanna".

Comment: Why use Apache at all? Just use iptables to map port 443 (_not_ 80) to port (e.g.) 4430. For what it's worth, we use nginx to SSL terminate and then have it proxy to cowboy using HTTP (but that's because we have an nginx module that needs to inspect the request).

Comment: Yes indeed, i meant https port, 443 and not 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put it in Apache:

- If you want to add more services later, they'd automatically benefit with SSL protection.
- If you need to debug something, you can `tcpdump` the data between Apache and your Erlang VM, which will be decrypted at that point.